# absolute path for stylesheets and javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a library which contains stylesheets and javascripts in one single folder and each javascript file is referencing another js file using relative path.

If i copy the javascript files to `public/javascripts` and the stylesheets to `public/stylesheets`, the library functions does not work properly.

Thus, i have to keep all javascripts and css together in one single folder.

My problem is i am not able to call the javascripts and the css using absolute or relative path in my view page.

If i try the following, it does not work because the rails app is not able to locate the jquery.cookie.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../public/_lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the public folder you should be able to access it normally:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```